# web api response json with "tilde"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Please, i need your help. I have data in oracle database ( i don't have acces for update this table, i only have read access).

TABLE States
Field Description ("The field value has **tilde**")

SOLICITAR COTIZACI**Ó**N

I have an service in Web Api 2.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("paginado")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetList([FromBody]RequestSolicitud solicitud)
    {
        int codeResult = 0;
        string messageResult = string.Empty;
        // logic from get list from DB;
        return Ok(new CompanyResult() { Message = messageResult, OperationCode = codeResult, Data = listFromDatabaseWithTilde});
    }
```

I run in local pc (Spanish configuration), the service response
Json result:

```
"DescripcionEstado": "SOLICITAR COTIZACIÓN",
```

But, i published in test server, (english configuration).
Json result:

```
"DescripcionEstado": "SOLICITAR COTIZACI¿N",
```

I used UTF8 in global.asax, but it was failed

3:     Encoding oldDefault = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedEncodings[0];
   4:     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedEncodings.Add(oldDefault);
   5:     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedEncodings.RemoveAt(0);

Ref. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/04/22/asp-net-web-api-content-negotiation-and-accept-charset/

WebApiConfig.cs

```
    public static void DisabledBehaviors(HttpConfiguration current)
    {
        var formatter = current.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();

        formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate
        };
        formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        current.Formatters.Remove(current.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
```

Comment: Did you add the same encoding at the page level? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp

Comment: Have you verified that the string is in UTF-8 when retrieved from the DB? I do not believe Json encoding has anything to do with that, it appears to be an issue with DB string encoding.